# Inkscape installed by Snap. Where to put Inkscape's Palettes, Symbols, Extensions, et cetera?

Tags: 18.04, snap, inkscape

Installed `Inkscape` from `Ubuntu Software` and now I have no idea where I could put palettes, symbols, extensions, icons etc.

There is a `.config` folder under `Snap/Inkscape/Current` but when I put these folders in there, nothing happens. If anyone can help me out, it will be great.

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution. I had to put the necessary folders in the folder

`/home/myName/snap/inkscape/5874`

You can add palettes, symbols, extensions etc. I can confirm that these 3 are working. I have also used " icons " folder, but it is empty at the moment. Hopefully it will work as well.

Comment: /snap/inkscape/*INKSCAPE_VERSION* or /home/myName/snap/inkscape/*INKSCAPE_VERSION*

Comment: V is. 0.92. This is some numbered folder